Build Failure with Python `match' Case Statements Using setuptools
I'm attempting to package a Python project into a .whl file using setuptools. My project codebase utilizes the new match case statements introduced in Python 3.10. However, when I run the command python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel to build the wheel file, the process fails. It seems the build process does not recognize or support the match case syntax.
To be exact, during the build process with setuptools and Cython, I encounter a CompileError specifically related to files containing match case syntax.
here is the mse of my code:
a = 10
match a:
    case 12:
        print('no')
    case _:
        print('yes')

here is the error msg:
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
a = 10
match a:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
xxx/xxx.py:153:10: Syntax error in simple statement list
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx-Segmentation/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize([...])
  ...
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: xxx/xxx.py

here is the code simple:
My environment is:

Python version: 3.11.7
Cython version: 3.0.10
OS: Linux, Ubuntu 20.04.5

and here is my quesiton:
Questions:

Has anyone successfully compiled Python 3.10+ code containing match
case statements with Cython, and if so, how?
Are there specific configurations or workarounds in Cython or
setuptools to support the match case syntax during the build process?
Or using a different build strategy recommended for handling Python
3.10+ features?

Thanks everyone~

Seems to be a known bug: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/5755

@tripleee so... no fix until now? it has been almost for 3 years... are there any other building strategy that can handle this syntax?

The simplest solution by far seems to be to avoid this syntax for as long as it is not supported by Cython. The bug report links to a fix which you could apply locally, but really, that way lies madness.

@tripleee I wouldn't call it a "bug", they simply don't support the syntax.

Yeah it's more a missing feature than a bug. Obviously it'd be nice to support, but the main people affected by it at the moment are those that are using Cython to try to obfuscate existing code bases. This isn't a use case we prioritise or encourage
